# Displaying an auto updating map off a Google Sheet

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to help witth rescue operations in Nepal.

I have setup a Google Form [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1bBZnQIO5C2ggoXVDfxM2qfUbcIvPN0pUrYoK9nWZYJc/viewform) and that information gets stored on a Google Sheet.

Now, I want to provide a map (OSM) that would autopopulate using data in the Google Sheet (there is a column with GPS coordinates.

Is this currently do-able? It would be ideal if I could provide an endpoint where various OSM maps could get the Google Sheet information from.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) to place markers and popups on top of OSM maps. [uMap](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/) might also be worth looking at.

Additionally there is also the [Humanitarian OSM Team (HOT)](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Humanitarian_OSM_Team) doing various tasks for helping the Nepal rescue teams. The [2015 Nepal earthquake](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/2015_Nepal_earthquake) wiki contains an overview, guidelines and specific tasks. It might be useful to discuss your ideas with HOT.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. I've been in communication with Google about this. It's currently not a feature, and they have no plans to add this feature in the future.

And I, for one, desperately need such a feature! I'd imagine if thousands of us flooded Google with requests for this feature -- maybe they'd add it?